# How to show those positioned text in the vector graph?

Tags: pdf-format

If we import this `.pdf` file with `"PageImages"`, we can see all information about it:

```
Import["https://selink.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/singlepage.pdf", {"PageImages", 1}, ImageResolution -> 200]
```

[image]

But I hope to get a **vector graphic**, so I use `"PageGraphics"`:

```
g1 = Import["https://selink.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/singlepage.pdf", {"PageGraphics", 1}]
```

[image]

I noticed that some of the text had disappeared where the arrow pointed. As I note the MMA 13.1 can deal with **positioned text** now. But I don't know how to show it normally in `g1`. And keep the `g1` is **vector graphic** still.

---

This is another `.pdf` file with **positioned text** for test:`"https://selink.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/singlepage3.pdf"`

Comment: Some possible complicated non native workarounds: 1: Maybe use a third party tool to divide the pdf page into parts (I saw one online that divides it in the middle but did not use it) and import each part and adjust the coordinates. Maybe it would work on smaller parts of the pdf.

Comment: 2: Maybe one could save the mesh from Inkscape Trace Bitmap and import that but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried doing it in two steps and it seemed to work. Your line

```
doc = Import[
"https://selink.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/singlepage.pdf", \
{"PageImages", 1}, ImageResolution -> 300]

ImageGraphics[doc]
```

I increased the dpi for ImageResolution a little bit because the text was a little fuzzy (if you go up to 500 the text gets really sharp but ImageGraphics takes a long time).

Comment: Not a `Vector`  format pdf.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here? Are you saying that the output of the answer code is not a vector PDF or that the input is not a vector pdf? From my understanding the question is asking how to produce a vector graphic from the PDF (regardless of whether it's vector or rasterized) and that is what this answer does.

Comment: The orginal pdf is a vector format pdf, that is,when we enlarge the pdf, the picture have the dynamic resolution according to the screen resolution instead of only fixed pixel,that is ,we cannot set  `ImageResolution -> 300`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the first image and those texts are encoded in some weird way and Mathematica cannot handle them.

The images can be extracted by `"EmbeddedImages"` but only the second image is returned,

```
Import[url,{"EmbeddedImages"}]
```

[image]

The formatted texts can be extracted by

```
url="https://selink.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/singlepage.pdf";
firstPageTexts=Import[url,{"PagePositionedText",1}];
```

and the fifth element in `firstPageTexts` should correspond to those texts associated to the first image, but Mathematica returns
[image: ```]

The supported character encodings in Mathematica are  `$CharacterEncodings`.
I have tried (de)coding those weird characters in `firstPageTexts[[5,1,1]]` with `ToCharacterCode` and `FromCharacterCode` but failed to recover the expected texts.